# Neo4j querying over 2 relationships and compute an aggregate function on the 2 relationship

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have this data model:

[image: Graph model]

With nodes:

- Client
- Vendor
- Product

And the relationships:

- Client - Recommend {qualification} -> Product
- Client - Buy -> Product
- Vendor - Sell -> Product

And i am trying to get the top sell products with the average qualification, i actually try this query:

```
MATCH (p:Product)<-[b:Buy]-(c:Client)
CALL{
    WITH c, p
    MATCH (c)-[r:Recommend]->(p)
    RETURN avg(r.qualification) as average_qualification
} 
RETURN p, c, count(b) as qty, average_qualification 
ORDER BY qty DESC
```

But the query return a row for each average_qualification per Client (Something like this):

[image: query result]

But i want to group per Product, so it needs to merge the rows where the products are the same, so for example the rows 1 and 4 will be merge and the average_qualification will be the average_qualification of the product (not divided by clients qualifications).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like:

```
MATCH (p:Product)<-[b:Buy]-(:Client)
WITH p, count(b) AS qty
MATCH (:Client)-[r:Recommend]->(p)
RETURN p, qty, avg(r.qualification) AS average_qualification
ORDER BY qty DESC
```

Which with this sample data:

```
MERGE (a:Client{name: 'A'})
MERGE (b:Client{name: 'B'})
MERGE (c:Client{name: 'C'})
MERGE (d:Client{name: 'D'})
MERGE (e:Client{name: 'E'})
MERGE (f:Vendor{key: 2})
MERGE (g:Vendor{key: 3})
MERGE (h:Vendor{key: 4})
MERGE (j:Product{key: 5})
MERGE (i:Product{key: 6})
MERGE (k:Product{key: 7})
MERGE (l:Product{key: 8})
MERGE (m:Product{key: 9})

MERGE (a)-[:Recommend{qualification: 4}]-(j)
MERGE (a)-[:Recommend{qualification: 4}]-(k)
MERGE (c)-[:Recommend{qualification: 3}]-(i)
MERGE (e)-[:Recommend{qualification: 3}]-(j)
MERGE (a)-[:Buy]-(k)
MERGE (a)-[:Buy]-(j)
MERGE (b)-[:Buy]-(l)
MERGE (d)-[:Buy]-(m)
MERGE (c)-[:Buy]-(i)
MERGE (d)-[:Buy]-(i)
MERGE (e)-[:Buy]-(i)
MERGE (e)-[:Buy]-(j)
MERGE (f)-[:Sell]-(i)
MERGE (f)-[:Sell]-(j)
MERGE (g)-[:Sell]-(k)
MERGE (h)-[:Sell]-(l)
MERGE (h)-[:Sell]-(m)
```

Will return:

```
╒═════════╤═════╤═══════════════════════╕
│"p"      │"qty"│"average_qualification"│
╞═════════╪═════╪═══════════════════════╡
│{"key":6}│3    │3.0                    │
├─────────┼─────┼───────────────────────┤
│{"key":5}│2    │3.5                    │
├─────────┼─────┼───────────────────────┤
│{"key":7}│1    │4.0                    │
└─────────┴─────┴───────────────────────┘
```

In order to understand this solution, and why it is different than yours, I recommend you to read about the concept of [cardinality](https://neo4j.com/developer/kb/understanding-cypher-cardinality/).

There is no need to count both the [:buy] and the (:Client). Keeping just one of them, and `count`ing it, allows us to finish the first `MATCH` with a list of products, not a list of clients. The same goes to the second `MATCH`, where we use `avg` on the `r.qualification`, allowing us to maintain the products list and not the recommendations list.